# Can I send a PID using CANBus fornat through an OBD2 bluetooth adapter?

Tags: obd-ii, can-bus, pid

I am interested in knowing if, by sending certain AT commands to the OBD2 Bluettoth adapter (for example the generic ELM 327 Mini) I can "program" this adapter and thus be able to send the PIDs in the format established by CANBus (CAN ID + 8 bytes). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, that's what these adapters are for. They feature a [very large instruction set](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Widgets/ELM327_AT_Commands.pdf), but typically you only need a handful to configure them to talk to your car.

Here are some helpful ones:

`ATSHxxx` sets the CAN Id, `ATCAF0` turns off automatic ISOTP formatting. Then you can send 8 bytes of unprocessed data.